# How to append after a specific id in jquery

Tags: jquery

Guys I have a table and I want to dynamically append a row with column inside it but not at the end, I want it to be appended after a specific id of a row. How to do that?

```
$('#add-another-file').live('click', function() {
   $('#to-upload-table').append('<tr><td><input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" ></td></tr>');     
});
```

That is my code, but it will append the new element after the last row.

Here's my html where i want the new row to be appended:

```
<table width="100%" style="border-collapse: separate;" id="to-upload-table">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="right">
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="add-another-file" name="add-another-file" value="Add another file" >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="right">
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="single-file">Single-file </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <input type="button" id="upload_file" value="Upload">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

As you can see, there are three buttons on the last part of the table, I want the new row to be appended just before those three buttons. After those file input types

Comment: You will have issues here as you are using the same ID more than once. A general computing concept is that IDs are used to specify **uniqueness**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery After](http://api.jquery.com/after/) :

```
$('targeted row to append after').after('<tr><td><input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" ></td></tr>');
```

You can check the list of DOM insertion methods here : http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: after is same as append?

Comment: Well, it should work. Are you sure that you have the good selector?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.eq()` with `.after()` if you don't have the `id`.

```
$('#add-another-file').live('click', function() {
  $('#to-upload-table tr').eq(Number Here).after('<tr><td><input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" ></td></tr>');     
});
```

Comment: What to put on the number part?

Comment: The table row number. First index in 0.