# How to append elements to appear at specific point in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, positioning, dom-manipulation

I have a popup that contains this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <span class="delete-x">X</span>
    <textarea class="text-box"></textarea>
    <span class="add-text">+ Add Text</span>
  </div>
```

When I click the span with "+Add Text", I'd like for an identical container with all the same elements (delete "x" span, textarea, and another "+Add Text" span) to appear below the container with the "+Add Text" span that fires the event. Here is the jQuery I have at the moment:

```
$('.add-text').click(_.bind(function(e) {
  var $container = $('<div class="container"></div>').appendTo(this.$contents); // Underscore.js bind sets 'this' to the context of the popup window. I create the container element and append it to the popup window.
 $('.delete-x').clone(true).appendTo($container);
 $('.text-box').clone(true).appendTo($container);
 $('.add-text').clone(true).appendTo($container);

}, this));
```

This successfully produces a new container with a textbox and the spans I want. But it appends it to the bottom of the popup. I want it to appear after the container of the specific "+Add Text" span I click. I've tried insertAfter() methods, and the jQuery (after) method but to no avail. There was another post on here from someone who was trying to do something similar but with table rows ([How to append after a specific id in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041341/how-to-append-after-a-specific-id-in-jquery)) but this hasn't worked for me.

I *need* to use the Underscore.js bind method to set the 'this' keyword to the context of the popup window, as explained in my comment in the above jQuery code. Were it not for this, I suppose I could just use .after($(this)) to get my container to appear where I want...

Is there anything else I can try?

Thx u
~Gaweyne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `insertAfter()` method to place the new `$container` directly after the one which was clicked on. Try this:

```
var $container = $('<div class="container"></div>').insertAfter($(e.target).closest('.container'));
```

Comment: You are pro. Thanks again.

I was very close. I tried setting the .after method to (e) and (event) - as an alternative to ($(this)) because of the Underscore.js method - but it didn't work.

I added insertAfter($(e.target)) to the above code and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help. Note that if you use `insertAfter($(e.target))` you'll be nesting the `.container` elements within each other - that's what the `closest()` call is used to avoid.